# Table row creation in rails while creating an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

This might be easy but i am not sure about this as on beginner level in rails.

learning rails model through a tutorial i found this --

```
Use t = Todo.new to create an empty row in the Todo table and stores it in t
```

After this i run the following command -

```
> t.todo_item = "Assignment 1"
=> "Assignment 1"
```

and `t.save` saves data successfully. Upto this point i am ok with it, however when i executed `Todo.all` command its showing only single row, i was expecting 2 one from the initial with id nil.

So is that the initial blank row that created while object creation destroys after second command run on db or is that something else.

Is nil values in rails/ruby refer to the `NULL`?
(As this is what i got from Todo.new [ id:nil todo_item:nil ...] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object isn't saved to the database when you call `t=Todo.new`.  It just creates an object in memory.

Calling `t.save` writes the record to the database.

You should be able to keep your sanity by doing this:

```
n = Todo.all.size # size of table before changes
t = Todo.new # create new object
t.todo_item = "Assignment 1"
t.save # save it to db
Todo.all.size==n+1 # should return true
```

Comment: is nil same as NULL (as iam from php/mysql background so not sure they are same or not )

Comment: `nil` is a Ruby term that can be considered equivalent to a `NULL` value in a database.

Answer (score 1):

`t.save` persists `t` to the database, and `id` is populated. Assuming you're using ActiveRecord, the `id` field is an automatic field and is auto-incremented. If you have a `Todo` with a `nil` value for `id`, that would indicate that object has not been persisted.